# SPUser vs. UserProfile vs My Settings

Tags: user-profile, my-site, spuser

I've been working woth FBA now, and my site uses both windows login and FBA login. They both work fine, and I've setup a MySite successfully to view profiles, and setup content sites for either kind of account.

No when I setup my FBA, I added some custom fields, say Job title and Department name for example.

When I edit my mysite profile, these fields don't appear, but no problem, this is expected, as I haven't written any code to match these fields together.

Now, when I'm on my regular site and click 'My Settings' from the top right hand corner dropdown, I get to a screen that seems to aggregate some fields from my DB and My Site Profile. As well as a new mystery Department field, and I'm sure I've Job Title in there somewhere, these have been seen (I hope I haven't imagined it) before the FBA work was even introduced so must be somewhere in SharePoint.

The other weird thing is when I'm on the main bit of my site, My Settings has an edit button, when I'm on My Site, it doesn't.

I might also add that my 'My Site' is a site collection within the main site and so has the same base url.

If anyone can shed some light on how I can synchronise all this information and make a simple one stop source of info for a user, that would be grand!

Cheers,
Bav

Answer (score 1):

The story is longer, but here are the facts to the simplest:

1. SPUser could have multiple identities for each of the Identity
   Providers you have setup, in most cases is Windows-Classic and
   Claims. Claims mode, in turn, supports Windows, ASP.Net Forms Based
   Auth and SAML Token often referred to as Windows-Claims, FBA-Claims
   and SAML-Claims. In simple words - could be different users (the
   user names start with "i:0#.w" for Windows accounts)
2. Windows Accounts are usually the ones that get data synchronized
   from Active Directory (if User Profile is not configured, therefore
   NO My Sites - you are left with only the User Information List
   available per each Site Collection where minimal data is
   available,such as AD account, SID, Email, First name, last name. -
   this is what you see via My Settings always.
3. User profile is the one that shows Department, etc. all many others,
   i believe about 57 pre-mapped upon configuration by default. Others
   could be added from external systems  -but these are NOT populated from AD in the case of FBA accounts that should be configured via a BCS connection and each of the properties usually coming from AD for all Windows accounts, must be manually mapped.

Comment: And if you "Replicate" the User Profile Property it will be sent to the User Info List.

Comment: Thanks for the information on this, we're having to learn SharePoint and things like this can get a tad confusing. I'm currently on the trail of setting up User Profile Synchronization, and mapping fields in the profile (no.3) to hopefully my FBA DB fields, time will tell how successful I'lll be!